# Proxy websockets connection within webpack-dev-server

Tags: proxy, websocket, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is it possible to proxy websocket connections within the webpack dev server? I know how to proxy regular HTTP requests to another backend but it's not working for websockets, presumably because the target in the proxy configuration starts with http://...

Comment: OP, could you provide some context on why you need to do this? Does `devServer.public` not suffice (seems like it would send *all* your WDS requests to that public domain/host)?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Version 1.15.0 of the webpack-dev-server supports proxying websocket connections. Add the following to your configuration:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
       target: 'ws://[address]:[port]',
       ws: true
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: They should put this bolded into the documentation. 
I wasted a few hours right now to figure out why socket.io is using polling instead of web sockets.

Comment: got it working.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611926/error-using-socket-io-along-with-webpack-dev-server/64725627#64725627

Answer (score 6):

@Mr. Spice's answer is correct. But it can be further simplified, check [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#websocket), it can be set as following, i.e. just add `ws: true` and keep other settings as usual.

```
// proxy middleware options
var options = {
        target: 'http://www.example.org', // target host
        changeOrigin: true,               // needed for virtual hosted sites
        ws: true,                         // proxy websockets
        ...
```

Comment: Sorry @Quilang, but I find your example insufficient to answer the question. The OP was looking for something in the context webpack-dev-server. I can't understand from your answer how that relates to a node.js middleware for proxying. What do the devServer: options look like?

Comment: webpack-dev-server uses http-proxy-middleware, so basically proxy settings of the webpack-dev-server is actually http-proxy-middleware options. They're same. I didn't get what he means by 'further simplified' though

Comment: @rosencreuz - I guess the simplification is that you don't have to specify both target: 'ws://' and ws: true - one of those is enough, according to the docs. This is useful when you want to proxy both http and ws, so you can just leave target: 'http://'

Answer (score 5):

Webpack dev server does not support proxying ws connections [*yet*](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/283).

Until then, you can implement proxying manually, by adding additional `http-proxy` to webpack server:

- Add new dependency to `package.json`:

  ```
  "http-proxy": "^1.11.2"
  ```
- Proxy websocket connections manually by listening to `upgrade` events

  ```
  // existing webpack-dev-server setup
  // ...
  var server = new WebpackDevServer(...);

  proxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer();
  server.listeningApp.on('upgrade', function(req, socket) {
    if (req.url.match('/socket_url_to_match')) {
      console.log('proxying ws', req.url);
      proxy.ws(req, socket, {'target': 'ws://localhost:4000/'});
    }
  });
  //start listening
  server.listen(...)
  ```

**NOTE (after using this for some time)**

There is an issue with proxying websockets as `socket.io` is used by WebpackDevServer to notify browser of code changes. `socket.io` may conflict with proxying websockets; in my case, connections were being dropped before handshake was returned from my server unless it responded *very* quickly.

At that point, I just ditched WebpackDevServer and used custom implementation based on [react-hot-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate)